# How to change job title in Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013, contacts

Anyone know how do I change my own **job title** in Outlook 2013's contact card? I'm unable to find a way to edit **my own** contact card, I can edit other people's though.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you on a company network? Or is this a standalone PC?

Comment: I'm using company laptop at home.

Comment: I would suggest checking with your company's IT department. There may be a policy in place which locks it.

Answer (score 8):

You need to talk to your IT department, This information is coming from Active Directory and only they can change that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/531785)

Comment: But it's true his computer is on the domain meaning this information is coming from the GAL and that gets it's information from Active Directory making the answer to his question for him to contact his IT Department and have them change the info in active directory

Comment: I just want to say that this is not the answer for everybody. I was able to edit mine in my contact card with no problem.